# Exclude text strings contained in a text file

Tags: bash

I have a text file containing following lines,

```
$ cat HELLO.DAT
A
FOX
IS
JUMPING
```

I have another text file containing

```
$ cat WORLD.DAT
A CAT
RUNNING FOX
IS GOD
AND JUMPING JACK
```

I want the following output

```
CAT
RUNNING
GOD
AND JACK
```

I tried

```
while read -r line; do grep -v "$line" WORLD.DAT; done < HELLO.DAT
```

but the output is,

```
RUNNING FOX
IS GOD
A CAT
IS GOD
AND JUMPING JACK
A CAT
RUNNING FOX
AND JUMPING JACK
A CAT
RUNNING FOX
IS GOD
```

So it removes the whole line once a match is found and also loops over WORLD.DAT for each listing in HELLO.DAT

I also tried

```
grep -v -f HELLO.dat WORLD.dat but then no output.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: the sample inputs/outputs show line #1 of `HELLO.DAT` being applied to line #1 of `WORLD.DAT`, line #2 of `HELLO.DAT` being applied to line #2 of `WORLD.DAT`, etc; is the intention to limit the removals to the same line #, or should the entries from `HELLO.DAT` be applied across all lines from `WORLD.DAT`? for example, assume line #4 (`WORLD.DAT`) is `AND JUMPING A JACK` ... would you expect the output to be `AND A JACK` (remove **just** `JUMPING`) or `AND JACK` (remove **both** `A` and `JUMPING`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso The intention is not the removals from the same line #.  Should look for the strings in the blacklist file in any order and line number and remove those.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v` excludes whole *lines*, but you only want to exclude words from a line. Without `-v` you could use `-o` to only print the matching part. Unfortunately, in `-v` mode there is no equivalent for `-o` that just deletes the matching part. Therefore you need a different command.

The following `awk` command reads the lines from the first file and deletes those words from the second file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]} NR!=FNR {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if ($i in a) $i="" }
  $0=$0; $1=$1; print
}' HELLO.DAT WORLD.DAT
```

Note that we delete only whole words separated by whitespace. The `A` from the first file does not delete the A in `CAT` from the second file.

`NR==FNR` is an awk idiom for checking if you are processing the first file.

`$0=$0; $1=$1` squeezes any sequence of whitespace. This is far from perfect but also somehow required, as your expected output didn't have a leading space before `CAT` or two spaces in `AND JACK`.

Comment: Just a small clarification. This works only if I am doing a line by line search i.e. the words in the HELLO.dat are also present in the same line # in WORLD.dat. A nifty solution to lift this restriction is to use

awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]} NR!=FNR {
  for (k in a) { gsub(k, "") }
  $0=$0; $1=$1; print
}' HELLO.DAT WORLD.DAT

credits to Francisco Lobos.

Comment: @Jalan  I don't think so, see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/QIwueLJ-g). In this answer, the order of the input file does not matter. Using `gsub` would be a step back, because it deletes every substring, e.g. the A in `CAT`. Also, `gsub` would interpret regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your problem using 'sed' command:

```
while read -r line
do 
  sed -i 's/\b'$line'\s*\b//g' WORLD.Dat
done < Hello.dat
sed -i 's/\s*$//g' WORLD.Dat
```

'sed' will replace words in WORLD.DAT (matched with words in HELLO.DAT) with empty string.

'sed' on third line can handle words having trailing & leading spaces and having leading spaces only.

'sed' on last line removes trailing spaces from the end of the line.

Comment: Is there a pipe before the sed on the last line?

Comment: No.
You can save it as a .sh or .bash file and execute it.